# HTML forms with two buttons

Tags: javascript, html

i have a html form with two buttons , one to submit the data via post .. and other to invoke a javaScript function. but both when clicked results in submitting.

```
<button onclick="validateData()" class="btn btn-warning" > Get Price Ranges </button>
<button type="submit"  class="btn btn-warning" >Search</button>
```

is it not possible have two buttons inside the same form ?

Comment: Are they both within the same form?

Comment: Also, can you please display your JavaScript? :)

Comment: I believe his question implies so.

Comment: @StevenTang ah yes, my mistake. Apologies OP

Comment: Try `<input type="button" value="Get Price Range" />` instead of button

Comment: yeah both are inside the same form

Comment: @Developer—or `<button type="button"...>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I dont know what code is inside your `validateData()`    function but try once like this...

```
 <button onclick="validateData(); return false" class="btn btn-warning" > Get Price Ranges </button>
```

But the best way is do like this..

```
<form action= "" onsubmit="validateData();return false" method="">
```

In action define URL and in method may be either `post` or `get`.by removing this

```
<button onclick="validateData()" class="btn btn-warning" > Get Price Ranges </button>
```

Comment: The OP's actual issue is that buttons in a form are, by default, submit buttons. They just need to change the non–submit button to `type="button"`. No additional javascript required. ;-) But you're right, putting validation on the form's submit handler is likely better again.